# R - Creating a new column based on a conditional observation and applying it to the master df

Tags: r

I have a very large dataframe (with ~15 million observations of 10 variables). The df is essentially results for a set of cities under various scenarios (conditions). Here is a simplified view of the df:

```
State City Result Year Condition1 Condition2 Condition3
AL Cottonwood 4.5 2000 p5 a10 d20
....
AL Cottonwood 2.5 2010 p10 a20 d50
```

I am trying to create a new column ("base") that is equal to a given city's result under the various scenarios for the year 2000. Because of the many scenarios, I am having a lot of difficulty doing this.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a comparison on each row for those conditions but the year 2000?

The way I would go about it would be to join the dataframe onto itself filtered to the year 2000. Assuming you dataframe is called df

```
require(dplyr)
df_base <- df %>% left_join(
  df %>% 
    filter(Year == 2000) %>% #get just year 2000 results
    select(-Year) %>% #remove year so that it does not join on it
    rename(base = result) #rename the result column of the cut dataframe to base
)
```

This will join by all other columns that aren't year, meaning the same state and city and all your conditionals, and return the full dataframe with a new column called "base" with the year 2000 result for state+city+conditions. If there are other columns you don't wish to join on you can either remove them in the select, or specify all columns to join on explicitly by using the "by" variable in the left_join.

Comment: That looks like what I'd like to do, however, it did not work. I get the error: Error in rename(., base = result) : unused argument (base = result)

Comment: You might need to change that to Result (capital R), I was testing on a dummy dataset I made and had lowercase column titles so must have forgot to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `ave` for calculation of records across same multiple groups and have *Result* return itself with `identity()`.

```
# YEAR 2000 CALCULATION
df$Base <- with(df, ifelse(Year == 2000,
                           ave(Result, Condition1, Condition2, Condition3, FUN=identity),
                           NA)
               )

# ASSIGN 2000 RESULT TO ALL OTHER YEARS
df$Base <- with(df, ave(Base, Condition1, Condition2, Condition3, FUN=function(x) max(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Not sure of performance across ~15 mill obs.